# The difference between bind and _.curry

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

So JavaScript's `bind` supports currying, but most people use some other library like `lodash` or `ramda` to do currying.

From first impression It seems like `bind` supports context changing, since that is it's intended role, e.g.

```
var replaceTest = replace.bind(this, 'test')

replaceTest('beta', environments)
```

The other curry methods don't have this.

```
var replace = _.curry(function (a, b, list) {
  // implementation
})
var replaceTest = replace('test')

replaceTest('beta', environments)
```

So are there any other difference between the two methods? Mainly I want to know if it makes sense to use one of those implementations when there is a native implementation present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bind()` doesn't actually do currying. What it does is *partial application*. lodash and rambda have a method called `_.partial()` that does partial application without setting the context object.

A function f is curried if calling f with one or more arguments is equivalent to calling f with one argument, then calling the return value with the next argument, and so on until you run out of arguments. Currying can be implemented with partial application, but it's a different thing.

If you genuinely want a curried function, it's probably best to use one of these libraries rather than roll your own. If all you want is partial application, `bind()` should be good enough, but if you're already using a library like lodash or rambda I'd consider using `_.partial()`. Also, it's worth noting that currying doesn't work so well with variadic functions.

P.S. [This blog post does a much better job explaining it](https://medium.com/@thinkfunctional/currying-partial-application-f1365d5fad3f).

Comment: Glad I could help.